Keycloak default mappers not showing in custom IdP
I am currently migrating a custom IdP, based on SAML, from Keycloak 18->25, the problem that I have now, is that the default mappers of Keycloak do not appear when i try to add them, like for example “Attribute Importer” mapper, I just see the ones hardcoded:

And in a default SAML IdP, they appear as normal:

Does anyone has an idea of what is happening?
Thanks in advance.
